# Passing string variable with spaces

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, post

In the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updateView(set) {
            $.post("<?php echo base_url("/show_cards/load_page")."/"; ?>"+set, function( data ) {
                $( "#content" ).html( data );
            });
        }
    </script>
```

'set' is a string variable which can have spaces in it. I'm noticing when it has spaces it's not working correctly. How can I fix this?

EDIT: For clarity, I'd like to keep the spaces intact.

Comment: I'd like to pass the string while keeping the spaces.

Comment: It doesn't have to be in the URL, I'm just trying to keep the data intact as it is.

Comment: As you say, I think you should replace the spaces as I have answered and replace all occurrences of the new character with spaces before any other operation with the data, to get the data intact.

Comment: As the URL doesn't support spaces and what you want is much similar to that of URL formatting you should try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to replace intermediate space (`' '`) with `'%20'` using `replace()`, and eliminate boundary spaces (`' '`) using `trim()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateView(set) {
    set=set.trim().replace(/ /g, '%20');
        $.post("<?php echo base_url("/show_cards/load_page")."/"; ?>"+set, function( data ) {
            $( "#content" ).html( data );
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

**NOTE:** that $.trim() is now deprecated for [.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

Use `set.trim()` to remove leading or trailing spaces and either

```
set.replace(/ /g,"+")
```

or

```
encodeURI(set)
```

to keep the spaces inside the string
(refer [When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent))

To do both in one go just chain them

```
set.trim().replace(/ /g,"+")
```

Note you may use %20 instead of the plus if you prefer.

But is it not a parameter? If so, perhaps you want to pass it as

```
$.post("<?php echo base_url("/show_cards/load_page")."/"; ?>",
  {"set":set.trim().replace(/ /g,"+")},
```

Comment: This is the only answer that answers this question in both parts. It's not about removing or trimming those spaces only.

Answer (score 2):

use **[Trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function updateView(set) {
          var set=$.trim(set);// by this  leading or trailing spaces removes  
            $.post("<?php echo base_url("/show_cards/load_page")."/"; ?>"+set, function( data ) {
                $( "#content" ).html( data );
            });
        }
    </script>
```

you can also use **[string.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)**

```
  var set=  set.replace(/ /g,"+") ;// like that way in this all the spaces removes
```

Comment: That only removes leading and trailing spaces

Comment: This question is not about removing spaces, its about keeping them and still letting the url to work. `'set' is a string variable which can have spaces in it`

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky very true. It is the actual concern i.e. the **intermediate spaces**.